# Type of std::normal_distribution depending on template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, ternary-operator

Rarely `T` can be int and it will hang at:

```
std::normal_distribution<T> distribution(0.0, 0.1);
```

This will be used in the next lines of my function and I wouldn't like to have an if/else with all the lines of code that depend on that. As a result I am trying to do this:

```
#include <random>

#define T int

int main ()
{
  std::normal_distribution<((std::is_same<T, int>::value) ? (float) : (T))> distribution (0.0, 1$

  return 0;
}
```

and I am getting these errors:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:Code gsamaras$ g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp 
main.cpp:7:69: error: expected expression
  std::normal_distribution<((std::is_same<T, int>::value) ? (float) : (T))> distribution ...
                                                                    ^
main.cpp:7:74: error: expected expression
  std::normal_distribution<((std::is_same<T, int>::value) ? (float) : (T))> distribution ...
                                                                         ^
main.cpp:7:77: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  std::normal_distribution<((std::is_same<T, int>::value) ? (float) : (T))> distribution ...
                                                                            ^
3 errors generated.
```

Any idea on how to fix this or an alternative?

Comment: `std::conditional`.

Comment: Ah, that should do the trick @T.C., thanks! Should I delete my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct X
{
    using float_t = typename 
        std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T, double>::type;
    std::normal_distribution<float_t> dist{0.0, 0.1};
};

int main() {
    X<int> x;
    X<float> y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I like your answer better than mine's! However, I wouldn't name it `X`, maybe something else..Thanks Pixel χημικέ!

Comment: @gsamaras: It is meant to be a placeholder-name for whatever template you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

[std::conditional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/conditional/) is the solution here:

```
#include <random>

#define T int

int main ()
{
  std::normal_distribution<typename  std::conditional<std::is_same<T, int>::value, float, T>::type> dist(0.0, 1.0);
  return 0;
}
```

which says that if `T` is an int, then give float as the type of distribution, otherwise give T.